# How to reduce the script compiled count. "Compiled script code is too long"

Tags: pine-script

I'm keeping my code as clean as possible. Have functions as much as I can, reduce the use of if/else and use conditional operator instead, I have no for loops.

I still get this message:

> Compiled script code is too long: 61637. The limit is 60000.

Would somehow limiting the calculations to the last X amount of bars help? If so, how to do that?
What would be the next best direction to reduce that number? I do have quite some arrays (that's the only thing I can think of)

I tried reducing the number of characters for variable names, to have less characters per line, that did not change the error number.

total lines of code: 3.7k (222k characters) I would say 700 of those lines are documentation.

thank you!

Comment: Maybe see if there is a way to reduce function calls with var keywords? I think that if it has to maintain it's own instances of those that could be an issue. But see if there is anything you can change that breaks the script but still compiles, if you drop a line from a function and it reduces the compiled count a whole lot you might know where to start.

Comment: I guess your script is using nested or just a lot of function iterations, 60k is an 'expanded' code length limit.

Answer (score 0):

That 60K max count is for compiled tokens, so variable names, for example, won't affect the count. 3K lines is in longish territory for a Pine script. While it's not necessarily to be expected, it's also not surprising you hit the limit. Besides refactoring code, which you seem to already have done, forking logic out to another script and using an external input to link them looks like the best way to go forward from here.

Comment: Thank you Luc! If I'm correct, I can only use 1 external source on that other script. It will not work for my case, as my script combines many indicators into one.

Comment: y correct. If you are using many indicators, then perhaps see if you are using the built-in version for all the ones you can. Quite a few of the most popular ones have Pine built-ins like `cci()`, `rsi()`, etc.

Comment: Yes, indeed, I use all the ones I can that way. And on the rest I optimise code to keep it as clean and lighter as I can. For now I managed to short it, I just expect it to give that error as soon as I add some new logic to it that is more than few lines of code :) 
thanks for your kind answers Luc!